# Sape для Joomla

Tags: joomla

Я понимаю, что это избитый вопрос, но как поставить Sape на джумлу?  Везде читаю, попадается какой-то мусор, непонятные указания и тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sape не ставил, но выход это создать ручками модуль в который поместить код сейпа и стандартно подключить или вывести модуль в нужном месте! А создать просто: создать директорию `mod_sape` и в ней файлик `mod_sape.php` и положить в директорию `modules`!